# difference in confidence interval for independent and dependent sample

Tags: confidence-interval

Using a dependent and independent measure on a study that has the same hypothesis and sample size (where independent looks at 2 different samples and dependent looks at 1 sample twice), why is there a difference in confidence intervals between the two measures?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to crossvalidated.

I presume that you mean that the dependent (paired) sample is half the size - the same number of measurements, but half the units (people).

There are several ways to think about this. One of them is that this happens because you've added information. When you add information your CIs would usually shrink ( and your p-value would usually go down). Here's a made up dataset:

```
ID T Score
1  1  11
1  2  32
2  1  17
2  2   9
3  1  12
3  2  23
```

If you take away the ID variable, you have unpaired (independent) measures. If you add the ID column, you are adding information.

Another way to think of it is how it is analyzed. In the paired data, you will calculate the difference, and then take the standard error of that. In the unpaired, you can't take the difference, you take separate standard errors.

For each person, their score is a function of the condition, plus a bunch of other person stable effects that you don't know about - which add to the error. If you have paired data, you've controlled for everything that is stable about the person - even though you didn't measure it. That reduces the error, which reduces the confidence intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you have paired data, each person serves as his/her own control, thus removing a huge amount of noise. The biggest reduction comes from the score on the earlier measure, but there are other reductions as well.

Suppose you are studying the effect of a weight management plan on human adults. If you measure people at the beginning and the end of your plan, with some in the control group and some in the treated group, then one big source of noise is the initial weight of the person.

You certainly wouldn't want to measure *different* (that is, independent) groups, nor would you want to ignore the weight at the beginning.